# Call API without manually generate token

Tags: wso2, access-token, wso2-api-manager, bearer-token, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm using WSO2 to create API (Bearer token). Then I want to configure it to auto-generate token (Basic Auth) and use response as access-token. How can I get that? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you explain your requirement further? You can create APIs in WSO2 API Manager and then invoke that using a bearer access token. If you mark this as unsecure, you don't need a token to access the API.

Comment: I do need to secure it, but for some reasons, I want to make it automatically generate token (pass 3 params: URL, user:pass). So the client, like using Postman, can invoke API without geting token manually.

Comment: i think it is my answer but I can't create one to invoke API and get the response as token.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java

Comment: You can do this at client side. For example if you are using a postman, postman can pass values from one API call to another.

Comment: I refer to this question. I solved it by using mediator.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252011/wso2-ei-can-i-use-mediator-to-request-another-api-and-pass-its-response-to-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WSO2 APIM, you can protect your API resources with different mechanisms (OAuth2, API Key, Basic Authentication) or you can disable the security.

**1. Disable API resource security**

If you don't want any securities to your API you can disable them in the publisher portal --> Select the API --> Resources --> Expand the resource --> Disable the Security button --> Save

[image]

**2. Secure API with Basic Authentication**

If you want to secure your API resources with username and password (Basic Authentication) you can enable it by navigating to the publisher portal --> Select the API --> Runtime Configurations --> Application Level Security --> Select Basic --> Save
[image]

In the developer portal, you can invoke the API resources with the username and password. The sample curl command is provided below.

`curl -X GET "https://localhost:8243/pizzashack/1.0.0/menu" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="`

Please note that the above solution is given for APIM-3.2.0. For more details on securing the APIs using Basic Authentication please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-basic-authentication/