# WSO2 EI: Can I use mediator to request another API and pass its response to the body request?

Tags: dynamic, wso2, token, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mediator

In my case, I want to add a dynamic value ("Bearer" + {access-token}) to the header mediator .
So before the header mediator, I want to invoke a get-token API and extract {access-token} element from its response. How can I get that ? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such requirements with mediation sequences. You can refer to this [blog](https://athiththan11.medium.com/wso2-api-manager-oauth2-protected-endpoint-aa51c62f0ad7) for more detailed instructions on how to develop a sequence for your requirement. The blog is written for the API Manager product, but nevertheless, you can follow the same to get it done in the EI.

A sample mediation sequence will be as following

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="oauth2-sequence" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- token generation to the oauth server's token endpoint -->
    <!-- add the base64 encoded credentials -->
    <property name="client-authorization-header" scope="default" type="STRING" value="MDZsZ3BTMnh0enRhOXBsaXZGUzliMnk4aEZFYTpmdE4yWTdLcnE2SWRsenBmZ1RuTVU1bkxjUFFh" />
    <property name="request-body" expression="json-eval($)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
    <property name="resource" expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')" scope="default" type="STRING" />

    <!-- creating a request payload for client_credentials -->
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <root xmlns="">
                        <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
                    </root>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args></args>
    </payloadFactory>

    <!-- set related headers to call the token endpoint -->
    <header name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', get-property('client-authorization-header'))" scope="transport" />
    <header name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="transport" />
    <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
    <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />

    <!-- change the token endpoint -->
    <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint>
            <http method="POST" uri-template="https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token" />
        </endpoint>
    </call>

    <!-- append the acquired access token and make the call to the backend service -->
    <property name="bearer-token" expression="json-eval($.access_token)" scope="default" type="STRING" />
    <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('resource')" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
    <header name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('bearer-token'))" scope="transport" />
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>$1</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('request-body')" />
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>

    <!-- perform a send or call to complete the execution of the backend service call in EI -->
</sequence>
```

Hope this helps you to start with implementation.

Comment: Tks so muchh. Can you explain "REST_URL_POSTFIX" part ? I'm not clear about it

Comment: The `REST_URL_POSTFIX` contains the remaining URL of an API Resource (ex: `/api/v1/operation` -> `operation` will be stored as `REST_URL_POSTFIX`). If you are invoking an API `/api/v1/operation`, and in the sequence, if you are trying to invoke an endpoint as `https://some-host/token`, the URL will result as: `https://some-host/token/operation`. Therefore, we have to remove that and again append it when calling the actual service. You can learn about the property in [here ](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties)

Comment: Can you explain the <payloadFactory> mediator in the end using for ? I'm so grateful for your help!

Comment: In the middle of the sequence, we are using a `PayloadFactory` to construct a payload to generate the Token. So, if you are invoking a POST request (which is the actual REST call), then the request payload you have sent will not be there in the EI, as we have changed the payload using the `PayloadFactory`. Therefore, at the end, we are adding another `PayloadFactory` to construct the actual payload again to send it to the backend.

Comment: You can capture the request payload using `$body` (without using `json-eval($)`) and update the `PayloadFactory` mediator's `media-type` as `xml`

Comment: I run it in Postman and it returns **202 Accepted**. I think the cause is Call mediator. Have you seen any case like this?

Comment: The given sequence is a sample created for API Manager. You may need to enhance the sequence a bit more (adding a `Send` mediator at the bottom) to send the request to the Backend servers.