# Cannot send request in mediation synapse in wso2 apim

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

We have two ways to send requests in wso2 APIM:
1- send mediator
2- call mediator
Unfortunately, I cannot use any of these mediators!
for example this request: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/
I need this approach for get token from a server and then use it in payload of main request for authentication.
could anyone help me please?! :)
I didn't get any error or special log!

```
<log level="custom">
    <property name="text" value="###############################33"/>
</log>
    <call blocking="false">                        
        <endpoint>                              
            <http method="GET" uri-template="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"/>                        
        </endpoint>
    </call>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="text" value="@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"/>
</log>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You need to get an auth token from an API and then call another API with that token, right? I think you will have to write a custom mediator to handle that.

Comment: @BoškoBezik Yes I mean that. but I cannnot run that mediator in WSO2 4.1.0 . I think send and call mediator have bug in this version.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unfortunately I cannot use any of these mediators!" ? What is the behavior you see? Do you see the logs in your custom seuwnece?

Comment: @ycr I mean I cannot use call mediator and send mediator. the logs is not good guider in this case. since It does not have any good information.

Comment: Shall we enable the wire logs and see the response? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/micro-integrator/classic-observability-logs/configuring-log4j2-properties/#wire-logs-and-header-logs

Comment: @Dil
Yes, The wire log says it has error in sending request. It does not depend on special url.

Comment: Can you attach the wire logs and error

Comment: Can you try enclosing the overall logic within a parent opening and closing tag. What I'm suggesting is something similar to this format: `<sequence name="main"><log> ... </log></sequence>`

Comment: If you can attach the wire logs, we will be able to look.

Answer (score 1):

You could find related blogs ["WSO2 API Manager & OAuth2 Protected Endpoint"](https://stackcheats.github.io/wso2-api-manager-oauth2-protected-endpoint/content/) and answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252011/wso2-ei-can-i-use-mediator-to-request-another-api-and-pass-its-response-to-the)

The idea is to

1. call the token endpoint with the appropriate grant type(usually client secret grant is used for system to system calls).
2. Then extract the token using the script mediator
3. Then use the that token to call the API attaching the token to "Authorisation Bearer:" header.

Please give this a try.

Comment: Thank you but my API is not OAuth2 and does not have client secret and client id. It is custom Authentication and not global. I described it in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447244/need-access-token-to-authorization-and-access-token-is-provided-with-another-ser
My problem is that "call" and "send" mediator don't work completely and I can not get response and log it. @RuwanAbeykoon

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the below properties before the call mediator. If your response is not a json payload, you need to set the expected payload content type to the ContentType and messageType properties.

```
<property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
```

After adding the above properties into the sequence, it should look like the below.

```
<sequence>
         <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
               <http method="GET"
                     uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c9ddf51330000b12c3f253a"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this, and say the response.