# need access token to authorization and access token is provided with another service with Basic Auth. Does WSO2 have this feature?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, access-token, basic-authentication, wso2-api-manager

I need this feature in WSO2 Publisher or Devportal:
I have one api that need dynamic access token and Also I have another api with static Basic Authentication to provide that dynamic Access Token. Unfortunately I could not solve this with mediation. The policy is simple But I don't know whether WSO2 has this simple feature or not?

process:  token api with basic Auth ==> provide dynamic access token ==> use access token in main api body and send.
Main API is our Endpoint in WSO2 API.
I could not solve this with Endpoint Security(Oauth2) and mediation(XML).
Version of WSO2-AM is 4.1.0 and this version is latest now.
[image]

Comment: What is the Api Manager version?

Comment: It is 4.1.0. and it is latest version of wso2-am. @ycr

Comment: Have you tried the OAuth2 password grant type? Also, can you explain the question further?

Comment: This api does not have client secret and client ID and I guess It is not Oauth2.
what is your opinion?

Comment: I only try Endpoint Security with grant type "Resource Owner Password" and I fill fake Client Secret and Client ID. @Thanuja

Comment: This requirement is not clear. Can you explain further?

Comment: @Pubci I Attached an image to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a vault, such as Hashicorp Vault, to fetch the the basic auth credentials.

From there use a custom sequence [2] that gets the token (step 1 in your diagram) and then get the token check results you need (step 2).

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/security/using-hashicorp-secrets/

[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/sequence-mediator/