# How to send http request in "script mediator" javascript language in WSO2 APIM?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, wso2, wso2-api-manager, mediator

I tried "fetch", "XMLHttpRequest", "jquery" functions to send http request in script inline mediator wso2 publisher. but in logs wso2 says "XMLHttpRequest" not defined and for jquery "$ not defined" and for "fetch" syntax error"
Is there any way to send http request in script mediator of wso2 apim?
this is jquey error.

```
[2022-08-25 15:53:25,508] ERROR - ScriptMediator {api:run:v1} The script engine returned an 
error executing the inlined js script function mediate
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: 
ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#5) in <Unknown Source> at line number 5
```

my mediator:

```
<script language="js" source="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
<![CDATA[
print("before sent########################################");

$.get("http://run.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed", function(data, status){
print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");

print("Data: DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD" + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});

print("sent########################################");
]]>
</script>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a browser object, which may not be supported at the script mediator as script mediator is a server side JS evaluation engine. You better use the "Call Mediator" to perform HTTP calls from the synapse config. Also i doubt jquery like libraries which targeted for browser rendition will work on the script mediator for the same reason.

Comment: @RuwanAbeykoon Unfortunately "Call Mediator" does not work too. I asked it in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73400906/cannot-send-request-in-mediation-synapse-in-wso2-apim

Comment: As @RuwanAbeykoon mentioned above, you can't use script mediator to do HTTP calls. You need to use the call mediator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the answer for the question : [Cannot send request in mediation synapse in wso2 apim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73400906/cannot-send-request-in-mediation-synapse-in-wso2-apim)

The same would help on here too.

Comment: I think, two questions are different. since that question want to use token but this question is just doing http request in mediator. @RuwanAbeykoon

Comment: ok, then better to use the purposely built call/send mediators which are purposely built for HTTP calls. You can use the script-mediator to prepare the payload to send and then use script mediator to extract the response payload to/from the synapse context as you wish. Script mediators primary function is to allow programatic access to synapse context for data manipulation.